# How to import multiple csv files in local DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, csv

I have a requirement of importing multiple files from a folder into a local DB table. column structures are same. Row count varies from 25 k to 200 k in each file.

which tool can be used to do it faster? like Sql server, oracle or Mysql

Comment: My opinion is that questions that explicitly solicit opinions are a bad idea. I don't know what "2 lakhs" means in this context, but it seems probable that *any* local database will be able to handle small amounts of data effectively. What database system you pick should not primarly be determined by the import speed, but by ease of access of the data once you've imported it.

Comment: SQL Server, Oracle or MySQL are not really "tools". You need to have an architecture first, and then try it yourself, and if it fails, then come here -- and not to use Indian words then either.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help, at least for MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<filename>' INTO TABLE <table_name> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (<columns>);
```

Comment: There would be many files in a folder and I have to import them all. All files will have same columns and I have to import them all in a same table

Comment: You can make a script in bash, explore the files in the folder, put the filenames in the `<filename>` field and save it as a `.sql` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server with OPENROWSET.
    1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql 
You can import multiple files in one query but it will depend on your needs.